# Delayed Windows cmd echo with GNU Make environment

Tags: windows, command-line, makefile, gnu-make

I have few simple targets which create some files for me.
Example:

```
$(MAKE_INA):
    @echo Building ASM compilation flags file $(notdir $(MAKE_INA))
    @$(foreach i, $(sort $(ASMFLAGS) $(PFLAGS) $(ALL_INC_DIR) $(cppGetPreProcessorDefines)), $(shell echo $i >> $@ ))
```

The target works fine, the file is being created and echo text displayed, but in that order (first the file is build then the echo is shown on cmd.exe console).

I guess that is related somehow with output buffering, but I was not able to find the way to flush the echos immediately.

Any hint? Is it even possible?

I am using Gnu Make 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up contexts here.

The first `@echo` line is a recipe line and is run by the shell when the target runs.

The second `$(foreach)` line is within the rule but is a make context line and is evaluated by make *before* running the recipe lines. Within that line `$(shell)` is also a make command and is run during the make expansion of the recipe instead of being run by the shell at recipe execution time.

To do what you want you can just use:

```
$(MAKE_INA):
    @echo Building ASM compilation flags file $(notdir $(MAKE_INA))
    @printf "%s\\n" $(sort $(ASMFLAGS) $(PFLAGS) $(ALL_INC_DIR) $(cppGetPreProcessorDefines)) >> $@
```

Which does the `echo`ing at recipe execution time (so has the right order) and uses a single call to the `printf` built-in to output to the file instead of running `N` calls to `echo`.

Edit: For Windows `cmd.exe` compat you need to use `echo $i >> $@ &` as the `$(foreach)` body so that `cmd.exe` runs multiple commands correctly.

If you did want to keep the `N` echo calls then you could use:

```
$(MAKE_INA):
    @echo Building ASM compilation flags file $(notdir $(MAKE_INA))
    @$(foreach i, $(sort $(ASMFLAGS) $(PFLAGS) $(ALL_INC_DIR) $(cppGetPreProcessorDefines)), echo $i >> $@; ))
```

Which has the `$(foreach)` *output* `echo XXX >> $@; ....; echo ZZZ >> $@;` as the recipe line to then execute during recipe execution.

Comment: The printf is not available on Windows (see tags), but I've tried to use the N echo calls without $(shell ). Unfortunately the $@ content is now like that: "--align=0 ;   @echo --core=tc1.6.x ;  ... " not like each item in new line and without "@echo"

Comment: Basically the echo from "foreach" is not executed but redirect to $@. Only the first one is evaluated, rest of them redirected as text to $@

Comment: Bleh, cmd.exe? I'm not sure you can get multiple commands on the same line sanely there. But you don't need to. And if you don't want the output on multiple lines in the output file (like your original would have done) then just use `@echo $(sort ....)`. (Assuming you aren't worried about the "shell" evaluating the contents of those variables of course.)

Comment: @ethan-reisner: Yes cmd.exe, I have to stick with it... Don't ask and unfortunately the multiline output is required by other tool

Comment: Try `echo $i >> $@ &` as the body of the loop.